# Division without multiplication, addition or division

Tags: java, bitwise

In context of preparing for a coding interview, I gave the division problem a go using Java. This is what I came up with. It's a little bit different to other solutions I've come across the interweb.

> Implement integer division without using multiplication or repeated subtraction (i.e. to divide n by d, you man not repeatedly subtract off d from n).

```
public static int division(int a, int b) {

    // For the basic cases
    if (b == 1) { return  a; }
    if (a == 1) { return  b; }
    if (a == 0 || b== 0) { return  0; }
    if (b > a)  { return  0; }
    if (a == b) { return  1; }



    int result = 0;
    int size = size(a) - 1;
    for (int i = size(a) - size(b); i >= 0; i--) {
        if((a - (b << i) >= 0)) {
            a = a - (b << i);
            result = result + (1 << i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}


public static int size(int a) {
    // The index of the most left 1 in the binary structure
    int temp = new Integer(a);
    int depth = 0;
    while (a > 0) {
        a >>= 1;
        depth++;
    }
    return depth;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `depth++` addition?

Comment: First thing I'd do:  `int add(int a, int b) { return - (-a - b); }`

Comment: I've clarified the question in my edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you run

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int a = rand.nextInt();
    int b = rand.nextInt();
    System.out.println(a + " / " + b + " == " + division(a, b) + " == " + a / b);
}
```

You'll see very clearly that the code is buggy. Investigate this yourself, and then come back to this post.

---

```
if (a == 1) { return  b; }
```

Is simply wrong.

```
if (a == 0 || b== 0) { return  0; }
```

should throw a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` in the latter case. It should do so *before* checking `a`.

```
if (b > a)  { return 0; }
```

Covers the case of `a == 0`, as long as you ignore negatives - so remove the `a == 0` check.

You don't even need these checks, though, so remove them.

You don't use

```
int size = size(a) - 1;
```

and it's also really bad style to have both an integer and a function of the same name anyway.

```
a = a - (b << i);
result = result + (1 << i);
```

should use `-=` and `+=`.

```
a - (b << i) >= 0
```

should be

```
a >= b << i
```

One then has

```
public static int division(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        throw new java.lang.ArithmeticException("/ by zero");
    }

    int result = 0;
    for (int i = size(a) - size(b); i >= 0; i--) {
        if (a >= b << i) {
            a -= b << i;
            result += 1 << i;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

One should deal with negative numbers. This looks as simple as

```
boolean negate = false;
if (a < 0) {
    a = -a;
    negate ^= true;
}
if (b < 0) {
    b = -b;
    negate ^= true;
}

...

if (negate) {
    return -result;
} else {
    return result;
}
```

However, this fails for `INT_MIN` since `-INT_MIN == INT_MIN`!

What to do? It seems like one could flip into the negatives instead, and flip all of the comparisons. I don't think this would work, though, since

```
a = INT_MIN
b = INT_MIN + 1
```

would result in `i = 1`, resulting in running `b << 1`, which overflows. This doesn't just happen with `INT_MIN` either.

The simplest thing, then, might be to flip to positive after casting to `long`. One can also simplify things by removing `size`, then, in favour of some fiddling with `b` like:

```
int i = 1;
while (b < a) {
    b <<= 1;
    i <<= 1;
}

long result = 0;
for (; i > 0; i >>= 1, b >>= 1) {
    if (a >= b) {
        a -= b;
        result += i;
    }
}
```

All in all, one gets the unfortunately long

```
public static int division(int left, int right) {
    // Prevent overflow on negation
    long a = left;
    long b = right;

    if (b == 0) {
        throw new java.lang.ArithmeticException("/ by zero");
    }

    // Normalize to positive longs.
    boolean negate = false;
    if (a < 0) {
        a = -a;
        negate ^= true;
    }
    if (b < 0) {
        b = -b;
        negate ^= true;
    }

    int i = 1;
    while (b < a) {
        b <<= 1;
        i <<= 1;
    }

    long result = 0;
    for (; i > 0; i >>= 1, b >>= 1) {
        if (a >= b) {
            a -= b;
            result += i;
        }
    }

    if (negate) {
        // Should not overflow
        return (int)-result;
    } else {
        // Truncation might overflow if
        // result is -(long)Integer.MIN_VALUE,
        // but this is correct
        return (int)result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit embarrassed now looking back at my code. Should have reviewed in myself more thoroughly before submitting. Thanks for all the great advice.

Answer (score 8):

A few things:

Why not

```
  int temp = a;
```

instead of:

```
  int temp = new Integer(a);
```

In regard to input validation, I see three things:

```
if (b == 1) { return  a; }
if (a == 1) { return  b; }
if (a == 0 || b== 0) { return  0; }
if (b > a)  { return  0; }
if (a == b) { return  1; }
```

1. Don't put it all on one line, even for 1-liners (Official style guide recommendations from Oracle/Sun, as well as Google, etc.)
2. a = -1 and b = -2 is OK?
3. Division-by-zero should not return 0, it should throw an exception.

Finally, the `size()` method .... is slow (and does not handle negative inputs). Just replace it with:

```
public static int size(int a) {
    return 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(a);
}
```

### Other issues

These lines have addition:

```
        result = result + (1 << i);
```

and

```
    depth++;
```

Comment: I wouldn't see a reason to do this in Java, but in VHDL (and possibly ASM) there can be advantages to dividing by bit-shifting and comparison.

Comment: @rolfl Why is it not okay to put the if statement on 1-line? When the block of the if-statement just contains 1 line, I find it easier to read when it's just on  the same line.

Comment: `int temp = new Integer(a);`:   `temp` isn't used so eliminate it completely.